# Incorrect currency format for Italy on Windows Server 2008 & 2012

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012

I have noticed that the currency format for Italy is inconsistent across different versions of Windows. Specifically, the position of the currency symbol.

To compare them, I am looking at the settings in *Control Panel -> Region -> Italian (Italy) -> Additional settings -> Currency*

Windows 10:
`123.456.789,00 €`

Windows Server 2012 R2:
`€ 123.456.789,00`

Windows Server 2008 R2:
`€ 123.456.789,00`

Based the answer [here](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5674/what-is-the-correct-way-to-format-currency-in-italian), I understand that the correct format is `123.456.789,00 €`, so why is it incorrect on Windows Server 2008 & 2012?

Is there any way to correct it, other than manually updating the format?

Comment: Have you tried to change regional settings?

Comment: @AlexanderTolkachev Yes, that works. I guess I wanted to confirm if this was a bug in Windows and whether there was a better approach for fixing it. If I update the regional settings, this would need to be done on any and every server where this settings was required in the future.

Comment: The default currency symbol format recommendation was changed in 2014 by the BSI (from 'nothing' to 'right').

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's bug. It's just change made by Microsoft in Regional Settings. May be there eas some changes in official papers about currency printing. Sometimes stuff like this happens and you should fix it.